# cant use MAMP after laravel php artisan

Tags: laravel, mamp

Hi today i was able to run a laravel project of a client, was a big problem, i achieve that after a lot of tests doing a sudo

```
sudo php artisan serve --host=127.0.0.1 --port=80
```

After that I restart Apache and MAMP and MYsql and i thougth that everything was ok.... But i try to run MAMP after editing de virtualhost, and PDO is trying to work with ¿laravel project? wtf..

Im desperate, how can i reset ¿mysql?, ¿apache?, i try to reset both , apache at least can go into localhost , and i get yes it work

Pls someone help i have a lot of jobs to do in MAMP

How can i see if something of laravel is still running, how can i close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I've understood your question correctly the below might help.

You can see what processes are running using the `netstat` command.

If you do `netstat -tapn` you should see something like

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9046/php5
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11300           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11211           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10231/nginx: worker
tcp        0      0 X.X.X.X:80              X.X.X.X:33801           TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 X.X.X.X:80              X.X.X.X:44907           TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0   1012 X.X.X.X:22              X.X.X.X:61850           ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 X.X.X.X:49308           X.X.X.X:443             TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

my artisan is the second line down in this case running on port `8000` you can tell this by it being a `php5` process. You can kill this by doing `kill PID` the `PID` in my case being `9046`.

The reason your probably seeing problems in the first place is that depending on your `MAMP` configuration that probably runs on port `80` your then trying to run `artisan serve` also on port `80` instead run it on the default `8000` then you can have both running.